# How To Convert IEnumerable To one object

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

In my Application Users can Have Multiple Roles , I Want To Convert List of Roles To One Common Role Object For Apply Permission

How i can handle convert List to Common role ?

```
public class Role
    {
        public boolData ListBools { get; set; }
        public ListId ListIds { get; set; }
    }
    public class boolData
    {
        public bool CanSale { get; set; }
        public bool CanBuy { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListId
    {
        public IEnumerable<Int64> Product { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Int64> Formula { get; set; }
    }
```

For Example this User have two Roles I Want to exucute common to one role object

```
 IEnumerable<Role> UserRoles = new List<Role>()
            {
                new Role(){ListBools = new boolData()
                    {
                        CanBuy = false,
                        CanSale = true
                    },
                    ListIds = new ListId()
                    {
                        Product = new List<long>(){1,4,58},
                        Formula = new List<long>(){2,7,}
                    }
                },
                new Role(){ListBools = new boolData()
                    {
                        CanBuy = true,
                        CanSale = true
                    },
                    ListIds = new ListId()
                    {
                        Product = new List<long>(){1,6,70},
                        Formula = new List<long>(){2,9,}
                    }
                },
            };
```

must convert To

```
Role Result = new Role()
            {
                ListBools = new boolData()
                {
                    CanBuy = true,
                    CanSale = true
                },
                ListIds = new ListId()
                {
                    Product = new List<long>() { 1, 4, 6, 58, 70 },
                    Formula = new List<long>() { 2, 7, 9, }

                }
            };
```

Comment: What did you do to come to the desired result manually? If you can figure that out, put it into code and you have it. Unrelated: poor naming. Do yourself a favor and reconsider names. Also, classes should start with a Capital ("boolData" => "BoolData")

Comment: I would Suggest using List of Role object or use var instead of Role Type to store the results into an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of `Any` and `SelectMany()` from `Linq`,

Like,

```
    var Result = new Role()
    {
        ListBools = new boolData()
        {
            CanBuy = UserRoles.Any(x => x.ListBools.CanBuy),
            CanSale = UserRoles.Any(x => x.ListBools.CanSale)
        },
        ListIds = new ListId()
        {
            Product = UserRoles.SelectMany(x => x.ListIds.Product).Distinct(),
            Formula = UserRoles.SelectMany(x => x.ListIds.Formula).Distinct()
        }
    };
```

Comment: You should use any instead of Select().Contains()

Comment: I did not get your comment

Comment: may to automatic result to without call every property

Comment: No, There is no way to define this properties automatically. because to assign values to properties in `result` object you need to perform above operations

Answer (score 0):

For list of Formulas and Products you can use SelectMany + Distinct:

```
  Role sum = new Role
        {
            ListBools = new boolData()
            {
                CanBuy = true,
                CanSale = true
            },
            ListIds = new ListId
            {
                Formula = UserRoles.SelectMany(x => x.ListIds.Formula).Distinct().ToList(),
                Product = UserRoles.SelectMany(x => x.ListIds.Product).Distinct().ToList()
            }
        };
```

I'm not suer how `ListBools` should be produced .... Maybe you should group all rules and join Formula/Product per boolData

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

- SelectMany merges many Product/Formula lists into one
- Distinct removes duplicates
- OrderBy ensures a ascending order
- Any checks if at least one CanBuy/CanSale property is true

Btw - I agree with the comments that say the Class/Property names could be be

```
    var products = UserRoles.SelectMany(m => m.ListIds.Product).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m).ToList();
    var formulas = UserRoles.SelectMany(m => m.ListIds.Formula).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m).ToList();
    var anyCanBuy = UserRoles.Any(m => m.ListBools.CanBuy);
    var anyCanSale = UserRoles.Any(m => m.ListBools.CanSale);

    Role Result = new Role()
    {
        ListBools = new boolData()
        {
            CanBuy = anyCanBuy,
            CanSale = anyCanSale,
        },
        ListIds = new ListId()
        {
            Product = products,
            Formula = formulas,
        }
    };
```